# NGINX => APACHE + SSPI

Tags: apache, nginx, windows-authentication, ntlm, sspi

We have an apache server with sspi authorization. We are using mod_auth_sspi. And now we need to proxy our api on another server via nginx. The main problem is how to make NTLM(as i right understand mod_auth_sspi uses it) to work via NGINX. I make guess that we need to proxy Authorization header. But i don't know how.

```
server {
     listen       8020;
     server_name  localhost;

     location / {
         proxy_pass http://apache.site.domain;
         proxy_set_header Host "apache.site.domain";
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
         proxy_connect_timeout 30;
         proxy_read_timeout 120;
     }


     error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
     location = /50x.html {
         root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
     }
 }
```

PS: Or maybe someone know mod_auth_sspi analog for nginx?

PS: Server with NGINX under Ubuntu 12.04, apache + sspi - Wamp under Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it won't work due to the way NTLM works and the way nginx works. See here: http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,72871,220959#msg-220959

Comment: But it may be possible with Kerberos authentication.